# Only SWDIO, SWCLK, GND three pins, how to debug

Tags: swd

I am new to microcontroller, I have a board just offer SWDIO, SWCLK, GND three pin.how to debug this board with iar through SWD

Comment: What board, or more important what processor? Many manufacturers have their own debug interface and protocol.

Comment: @Oldfart  stm32f030f4, the board is a diy. I want use it to control motor speed.

Comment: Debug STM32 MCU with what debugger? Some debuggers do not worl with only three wires; many need supply voltage so they know ay which voltage levels to communicate.

Comment: I used a ST-Link, and finally sovled the probelm.I forgot to update the question for a long time.Sorry for my limit of knowledge